# From Import in Python is not importing my modules

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, importerror, python-3.9

I have several custom module scrips in my python project that are all in a folder that is one directory down named "modules". After about a day of use on every machine I touch, importing these modules starts spitting out this error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'letters' from 'modules' (C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\modules.py)
```

The code for importing custom modules is here.

```
    from modules import letters
    from modules import sfx
    from modules import bgm
    from modules.colors import colors, hex2dec
    from modules import lessons
    from modules import sessions
    from key import key
```

The project folder looks like this (folders and files unrelated to the issue excluded):

```
formapp
├───modules
│   ├───bgm.py
│   ├───bot_ir.py
│   ├───chat.py
│   ├───colors.py
│   ├───formbot.py
│   ├───ir.py
│   ├───lessons.py
│   ├───letters.py
│   ├───sessions.py
│   └───sfx.py
├───app.py
├───key.py
```

For the most part, `sys.path.append(r"modules")` had worked to solve this issue however hex2dec in colors.py still caused errors. Regardless, of the 15 people working on this project this error only appears for me so I should not have to append a new folder to search for modules. The only thing that separates me from the other 15 people is that I was using formbot.py

Here is the code for formbot.py.

```
import requests
import time

class FormBot():
    def __init__(self, username, password, timeout=0, host='127.0.0.1', port=420)       :
        self.host = '192.168.10.69'
        self.port = 420
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.loggedin = False
        time.sleep(timeout)
        self.login()
        print('logged in as', username)


    #change "userType": "login", to "usertype": "new" on first time use
    def login(self):
        loginAttempt = requests.post(url="http://"+self.host+":"+str(self.port)+"/login", data={"username": self.username, "password": self.password, "userType": "new", "bot": "True", "forward":"/"})



#forbius login

Forbius = FormBot('Forbius', 'Password#1')
```

I have also tried reinstalling Python entirely and that has not worked.

To test, I tried running a fresh copy of the main branch on a computer affected by this issue and got the same error. The same code works fine on other machines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try adding an `__init__.py` file inside the modules folder

inside the `__init__.py` file put:

```
from .letters import *
from .sfx import *
from .bgm import *
.
.
.
```

Comment: You need the file `init.py` itself, but there's no need for the wildcard imports. Just leave it empty.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add a file called `__init__.py` to your `modules` folder. The file can be empty. Review this SO thread for more details: [What is __init__.py for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448271/what-is-init-py-for)